# Quarkus: how can I ignore tests written for different test profile and test tags

Tags: quarkus

I'm strugling with finding info of how to ignore some tests that were exclusively     written for some "other" profile when runing default **mvn clean install**.

I need different tests for different use cases:

1. CRUD operations on entities with hibenate-orm **create-drop** option
2. other operations on entities with hibernate connected to mock database (hence integration tests, with hibenate-orm **validate**)

I've got my custom test profile

```
public class IntegrationProfile implements QuarkusTestProfile {


  @Override
  public String getConfigProfile() {
    return "integration";
  }


  @Override
  public Set<String> tags() {
    return Collections.singleton("integration");
  }

}
```

And use it like this:

```
@QuarkusTest
@TestProfile(IntegrationProfile.class)
public class ArticleIntegrationRepositoryTest { ... }
```

I run these tests in cmd line like:

```
mvn -Dquarkus.test.profile.tags=integration clean install
```

But when I run

```
mvn clean install
```

all tests, including "profiled" ones are executed and I don't want that.
Is there any way to annotate these "other" tests so they don't get run unles I specificaly execute them with **mvn -Dquarkus.test.profile.tags=integration clean install**

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

First I addet junit 5 tag to to my integrations test classes

```
@Tag("integration")
```

then I updated my pom.xml files accordingly.
For **maven-surfire-plugin** I added executions to ignore my integration tags on tests

```
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>default-test</id>
    <goals>
       <goal>test</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <excludedGroups>integration</excludedGroups>
    </configuration>
 </execution>
</executions>
```

and added new integration profile to include only these tests when needed

```
<profile>
  <id>integration</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>quarkus-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <groups>integration</groups>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
         ...
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

now **mvn clean install** ignores my "integration" tests and **mvn -Dquarkus.test.profile.tags=integration -P integration clean install** executes only integration tests